# query item using linq and return type in the same statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two lines of code which first returns an item from a query and then creates another item with the values of the first query. i would like to combine these two lines into one statement. Keep in mind that the result of the first query might be null on some occasions.

```
var x = uow.Profiles.FindByID(profileId).Competitor;

return Json(new Organisation() { Name = x.Name, ID = x.ID, IsClient = x.IsClient, IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I don't get it ? What's the problem ? What exactly is the question ? Are you concerned about the null cases ?

Comment: There is no point in making those two lines even more unreadable... Split them up instead.

Comment: you're just desperate to use linq? this is not fit for it, because there is no IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a null check if this is your concern:

```
var result = uow.Profiles.FindByID(profileId);

if(result != null)
{
   var competitor = result.Competitor;
   return Json(new Organisation() { Name = competitor.Name, ID = competitor.ID, IsClient = competitor.IsClient, IsDeleted = competitor.IsDeleted }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

return null; // or whatever you can default to
```

Not sure exactly what the problem is and how LINQ could help (you don't necessary *have* to use it), just make sure your code is readable.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** finally using IEnumerable (I assume Profiles is one)

```
ouw.Profiles.Single(p => p.Id == profileId).Select
(p => Json(
    new Organisation()
    {
        Name = p.Competitor.Name,
        ID = p.Competitor.ID,
        IsClient = p.Competitor.IsClient,
        IsDeleted = p.Competitor.IsDeleted
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
);
```

Comment: but by `FindByID(profileId).Competitor` you can judge that also FindByID does not return IEnumerable

Comment: I think `FindByID` is not `IEnumerable` either